# Volume using spherical coordinates-finding theta!

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $V$ be the region in $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by the inequalities $z^2\ge x^2+y^2$, $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1$, and $z\ge 0$. Sketch the region $V$ and find its volume?

I have sketched $V$ but to find the volume I have  written the region in spherical coordinates but I don't understand how to determine the value of theta or phi? I know what theta and phi are for a point in space but don't how to find it for a region in space.

Also how do you know when to use spherical coordinates and when to use cylindrical ones?

Comment: find within the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$where does $x^2+y^2=z^2$

Answer (score 0):

The restriction of $\theta$ to the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ comes from the third inequality, $0\leq z$. The further restriction of $\theta$ to the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$ comes from the first inequality, $x^2+y^2\leq z^2$. In spherical coordinates this becomes,

$$r^2\sin^2{\theta}\cos^2{\phi}+r^2\sin^2{\theta}\sin^2{\phi}\leq r^2\cos^2{\theta}\\
\iff r^2\sin^2{\theta}\leq r^2\cos^2{\theta}\\
\iff 0\leq r^2\left(\cos^2{\theta}-\sin^2{\theta}\right)\\
\iff 0\leq r^2\cos{(2\theta)}\\
\iff \theta\in[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]\cup[\frac{3\pi}{4},\pi]~\lor~r=0.$$

Comment: sorry but I don't understand what is going on why can't I  just tell from the sketch?